# How to set value of a property based on values of other properites of a Node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have different nodes in my Neo4J database. Each type of node has various fields attached to it.
A node of type **THREAT** has the following properties:

- id
- description
- impact
- name
- rating

I have the values of all the properties except the rating at the time of the creation of nodes. It is because the **rating** property depends on values from other nodes, or the application will send it to neo4j.

An example of a Threat node script to create it:

```
(t_repudiate: THREAT {name: "NON_REPUDIATION", desc: "Break Non-repudiation", impact: "Repudiate Transactions", rating: ""}),
```

An example of a rating condition is as follows:

- rating of NON_REPUDIATION is **high** if **PII/PHI > 5,000**.
- rating of NON_REPUDIATION is **high** if **integrity requirement  is (high or critical)**

Is there any way I could achieve this using the Neo4J script?

Comment: There are some missing details, in the question, what are `PII`, `PHI` and `integrityRequirement`? Which nodes do they belong to and for a given `Threat` node, what are the target nodes from which these properties, should be fetched?

Comment: take a look at this https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/

Comment: @CharchitKapoor PII, PHI are values available in MySQL database connected to the same app where Neo4J is connected.

Comment: ok, so while creating threat nodes can't we calculate rating as well from the values present in mysql?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor yeah I can do that. But is there any way to get it done in Neo4J?

Comment: You can do that, but how do you intend to access MySQL from within neo4j. Are you using this apoc function https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.load/apoc.load.jdbc/

Comment: If possible can you give us some sample mysql rows and the corresponding neo4j output.